# Can React Native app (means same codebase) be turned into mobile web app?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-native

Whether the same REACT codebase can be shared across mobile web and mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot. React Native uses a bunch of pre-built components that are really just native iOS components wrapped in Javascript. For example, you could use `<div>` or `<span>` in React but in React Native you'd have to use `<Text>`, images can only be displayed in `<Image>` components, etc. There are also stricter limitations on what styles, data, or nested components each React Native component can have.

On a side note, trying to do this goes against the React philosphy -> 'Learn once, write anywhere'. You can try taking a look at [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) if you're interested in something that ports easily over to mobile apps.