# Can React Native be used to build Progressive Web App

Tags: javascript, react-native, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to build a Progressive Web App (PWA) that initially targets the desktop, but eventually will work on mobile as well using a single codebase.

It's basically a CRUD app consisting of a navigation bar, geolocation and some forms that allow the user to add records and images to a database. For devices that have a camera, I want to offer the option of using that for the image upload. With the exception of that.

I have experience creating PWA with Ionic & Angular, but after learning React and create native I don't want to go back in angular anymore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740197/can-react-native-app-means-same-codebase-be-turned-into-mobile-web-app. You might want to read this answer first. React Native is only for mobile and while you can reuse logic code for web and mobile app, a completely single code base is not feasible.

Comment: The "native" implies native (os-specific) apps as opposed to web apps. You might consider Polymer (https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit) or Vue (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa) as alternatives.